# What is the maximum scrape_interval in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I used Prometheus to measure business metrics like:

```
# HELP items_waiting_total Total number of items in a queue
# TYPE items_waiting_total gauge
items_waiting_total 149
```

I would like to keep this data for very long term (5 years retention) and I don't need high frequency in scrape_interval. So I set up `scrape_interval: "900s"`.

When I check the graph in Prometheus with 60s resolution, it shows that flapping, but it is not true.

[image]

The question is, what is the maximum (recommended) scrape_interval in Prometheus?

Comment: Prometheus explicitly isn't for long term storage of metrics. They recommend exporting to influxdb or something similar to support the storage use case.

Comment: If you need storing data with scrape interval exceeding 2 minutes while maintaining compatibility with PromQL, then try storing the data to [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/). It supports time series with arbitrary long scrape intervals.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not advisable to go above about 2 minutes. This is as staleness is 5 minutes by default (which is what's causing the gaps), and you want to allow for a failed scrape.

Comment: Thanks @brian-brazil I'll set scrape_interval to 2 minutes.

Comment: Seems to be documented in [Staleness](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) and can be configured with `--query.lookback-delta` command line flag.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore gaps, it is possible to use some [aggregation_over_time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time)  functions to get your DATA from Prometheus.

```
max_over_time(items_waiting_total[900s])
```

This is useful for situations where frequent gathering of DATA is expensive for collector.

Answer (score 0):

By default Prometheus fills gaps for up to 5 minutes after each raw sample stored in the database. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) for details. If you need to fill bigger gaps between raw samples, then the [last_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#last_over_time) function can help. Just specify the maximum gap duration in square brackets in order to fill gaps. For example, the following query would fill gaps for `items_waiting_total` time series for up to 900 seconds:

```
last_over_time(itmes_waiting_total[900s])
```