# http_request_duration_seconds_sum / http_request_duration_seconds_count shows 2 graphs

Tags: jquery, prometheus, grafana, dashboard

I have a Grafana dashboard, where I try to plot some of the prometheus metrics.

I am trying to calculate the average response time for 2 endpoints using the formula:

```
http_request_duration_seconds_sum / http_request_duration_seconds_count
```

but when plotting the query into the Grafana graph panel, I get 4 graphs (2 for each) instead of only 2, which I don't understand.

[image: snippet from Grafana]

Can anyone tell me, why there are 4 curves instead of 2?
The two on the top are from the same query and likewise for the two in the buttom.

**UPDATE**

Is adding

```
sum(rate(http_request_duration_sum))[24h] / sum(rate(http_request_duration_count))[24h]
```

the answer? That gives me 2 curves instead of 4, but not sure if the result is what I am looking for (being the average response time for the endpoint).

Comment: Do you have http_request_duration_sum metric by default in Prometheus?
If not, which exporter provides it?

Comment: Why do I need to apply sum when I have already used http_request_duration_seconds_sum ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the following query:

```
sum(rate(http_request_duration_sum))[24h] / sum(rate(http_request_duration_count))[24h]
```

is the answer, I am looking for, giving me the average response time in seconds and only 1 curve pr query.

*Of course* the scrape_interval should **not** be 24h, so I've set it to [1m] instead. <- this according to this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230057/what-is-the-maximum-scrape-interval-in-prometheus)

Comment: sum(irate(http_request_duration_sum{service=~"$service"}[2m])) by (service) / sum(irate(http_request_duration_count{service=~"$service"}[2m])) by (service)

Comment: just paste one used in production

Comment: thanks suiwenfeng. Yup, it's the same, but using irate instead of rate. In my case I would probably sort by (instance), but it gives the same output nonetheless.

Comment: It is recommended to use `rate()` instead of `irate()` - see [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832).

Comment: @suiwenfeng what does the 'by (service)' do in the query?

Comment: @Ayushmati it means this aggragation calculated group by service.

Answer (score 8):

The `http_request_duration_sum` and `http_request_duration_count` are metrics of [counter type](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter), so they usually increase over time and may sometimes reset to zero (for instance when the service, which exposes these metrics, is restarted):

- The `http_request_duration_sum` metric shows the sum of all the request durations since the last service restart.
- The `http_request_duration_count` metric shows the total number of requests since the last service restart.

So `http_request_duration_sum / http_request_duration_count` gives the average request duration **since the service start**. This metric isn't useful, since it smooths possible request duration spikes and the smooth factor increases over time. Usually people want to see the average request duration over the last `N` minutes. This can be calculated by wrapping the counters into [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function with the needed lookbehind duration in square brackets. For example, the following query returns the average request duration over the last 5 minutes (see `5m` in square brackets):

```
increase(http_request_duration_sum[5m]) / increase(http_request_duration_count[5m])
```

This query may return multiple time series if the `http_request_duration` metric is exposed at multiple apps (aka jobs) or nodes (aka instances or scrape targets). If you need to get the average request duration over the last 5 minutes per each job, then the [sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) function must be used:

```
sum(increase(http_request_duration_sum[5m])) by (job)
  /
sum(increase(http_request_duration_count[5m])) by (job)
```

Note that the `sum(...) by (job)` is applied individually to the left and the right part of `/`. This isn't equivalent to the following **incorrect** queries:

```
sum(
  increase(http_request_duration_sum[5m]) / increase(http_request_duration_count[5m])
) by (job)
```

```
avg(
  increase(http_request_duration_sum[5m]) / increase(http_request_duration_count[5m])
) by (job)
```

Since the first incorrect query calculates the sum of average response times per each `job`, while the second incorrect query calculates the average of averages of response times per each `job`. This is not what most users expect - see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95909/why-is-an-average-of-an-average-usually-incorrect) for details.

Comment: Is there a list of all the http metrics and their definition?

Comment: Every application exports its own set of metrics. So there is no a list of http-related metrics with their definition. Both Prometheus and Grafana support metric name auto-completion. For example, if you start writing `http_` in the query input field, then you'll see a list of metrics starting from`http_`. As for the description of these metrics, some applications provide metrics' description directly on the `/metrics` page from where these metrics are collected by Prometheus. Otherwise the best approach is to search metrics' description in Google.

Comment: Saying that those metrics are Counters is a wrong statement. [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#count-and-sum-of-observations) defines them Histograms or Summaries. However (as @valyala said) it depends on the  implementation. The famous Micrometer Java library used by SpringBoot applications implements it as a [Summary](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/05e65342ac8d87b91043204def52a8b732620930/implementations/micrometer-registry-prometheus/src/main/java/io/micrometer/prometheus/PrometheusMeterRegistry.java#L361) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those metrics coming from prometheus are counters. So, you should add rate/irate. Use irate for volatile and fast moving metrics