# Group counts by time in Grafana

Tags: grafana, metrics

I have a counter metric which I want to display as requests/time period. How can I display it in Grafana? All I was able to do was to show it as increasing value:
[image]

Comment: can you please be a bit more specific? maybe this will lead you into the right way, if it is what I think you mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58725189/http-request-duration-seconds-sum-http-request-duration-seconds-count-shows-2/58726800?noredirect=1#comment103746805_58726800

Answer (score 0):

You need to `derivate` (calculate rate of the change) your metric on the time series database (TSDB) level. Please check documentation of your used TSDB.

For example: [InfluxDB DERIVATE documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#derivative)